# Reduce returns false on equation solvable by LInearSolve

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I was looking for general solutions of an equation I already solved for specific values with LinearSolve, but using Reduce returned False.

Here's the code:

```
B = {{c, 1}, {c, d}, {1, c}};
v = {1, 1, 2};
Reduce[B.x == v, {c, d}, Reals]
```

This returned False

The case I solved was:

```
d = 1;
c = 2;
LinearSolve[B, v]
```

This returned {0, 1}

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Try `Reduce[B.{x, y} == v, {x, y}, Reals]`.

Comment: Technically, you should be doing `LeastSquares[{{c, 1}, {c, d}, {1, c}}, {1, 1, 2}]`.

Comment: To make that explicit, you can't use a symbolic vector in `Reduce` (`x` in your example). Write the components.

Comment: Writing x as a vector {x,y} did the trick, thank you all!

Comment: @Lorad, would you write that up as an answer to your question? Self-answers are encouraged here, and it would help to have this question show up as answered if anybody else in the future might run across it.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comments I realized my mistake and was able to solve it quite easily.
My mistake was that I put an x as placeholder for a 2-dimensional vector, but mathematica interprets that as just a variable. If I write {x,y} instead of x, mathematica can solve the equation.

```
Reduce[B.{x, y} == v, {c, d}, Reals]
```